# Problems with unwanted padding inside table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, cellpadding

I have this table and custom CSS code here in https://jsfiddle.net/g9a4sL6r/

As you can see, the table row have 28px height, while the content only has 14px height. I want to get rid of the additional padding, so the table row will also have height 14px.

Here is my code as needed by stackoverflow:

```
<table class="table1" style="width:100%;" border="1px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sidehoved">
      <td class="sidehoved">
        <strong>BIG 13033 - Ø4 AARhus</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="sidehoved" align="right">
        <strong>Dok. nr.&nbsp;</strong><strong>K01_C08_XXX</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sidehoved">
      <td class="sidehoved">
        Bygningsdelsjournal
      </td>
      <td class="sidehoved" align="right">
        Dato:&nbsp;2016-10-24
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sidehoved">
      </td>
      <td class="sidehoved" align="right">
        Rev.dato: -
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sidehoved">
      <td class="sidehoved">
        <em>X = revideret siden sidste udsendelse</em>
      </td>
      <td class="sidehoved" align="right">
        Side: <span class="page"></span>/<span class="topage"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
table.journal-table {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  margin: 0px /* remove space around unordered lists */;
}

table.journal-table table, th, td
{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  margin: 0px /* remove space around unordered lists */;
  white-space: pre-line;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* Make white + gray stripes */

table.journal-table tr:nth-child(even){background: #FFF}
table.journal-table tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #e9e9e9}

ul {
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 0px /* remove indents on undordered liste */;
  margin: 0px /* remove space around unordered lists */;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* set size of heading font + background color = medium gray */
table.journal-table th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black /* Show line below head */;
  border-top: 1px solid black /* Show line above head */;
  border-collapse: collapse /* Show solidlines in head */;
  font-size: 8pt;
  text-align: left;
  background: #FFF;
}

/* Sidehoved og sidefod opsætning */
p {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

 /* opsætning af tabel i sidehoved og sidefod */
table.table1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
.table1 td:nth-child(1) {width: 70%;}
.table1 td:nth-child(2) {width: 30%;}
.table1 td:nth-child(3) {width: 2%;}
.table1 td:nth-child(4) {width: 27;}

td.sidehoved {
  padding: 0px;
}

tr.sidehoved {
  padding: 0px;
}

/* Indsæt som class="sidefod" for at opsætte sidefod seperat */
p.sidefod {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `white-space: pre-line`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
table.journal-table {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  margin: 0px /* remove space around unordered lists */;
}

table.journal-table table, th, td
{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  margin: 0px /* remove space around unordered lists */;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* Make white + gray stripes */

table.journal-table tr:nth-child(even){background: #FFF}
table.journal-table tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #e9e9e9}

ul {
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 0px /* remove indents on undordered liste */;
  margin: 0px /* remove space around unordered lists */;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* set size of heading font + background color = medium gray */
table.journal-table th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black /* Show line below head */;
  border-top: 1px solid black /* Show line above head */;
  border-collapse: collapse /* Show solidlines in head */;
  font-size: 8pt;
  text-align: left;
  background: #FFF;
}

/* Sidehoved og sidefod opsætning */
p {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

 /* opsætning af tabel i sidehoved og sidefod */
table.table1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
.table1 td:nth-child(1) {width: 70%;}
.table1 td:nth-child(2) {width: 30%;}
.table1 td:nth-child(3) {width: 2%;}
.table1 td:nth-child(4) {width: 27;}

td.sidehoved {
  padding: 0px;
}

tr.sidehoved {
  padding: 0px;
}

/* Indsæt som class="sidefod" for at opsætte sidefod seperat */
p.sidefod {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1" style="width:100%;" border="1px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sidehoved">
      <td class="sidehoved">
        <strong>BIG 13033 - Ø4 AARhus</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="sidehoved" align="right">
        <strong>Dok. nr.&nbsp;</strong><strong>K01_C08_XXX</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sidehoved">
      <td class="sidehoved">
        Bygningsdelsjournal
      </td>
      <td class="sidehoved" align="right">
        Dato:&nbsp;2016-10-24
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sidehoved">
      </td>
      <td class="sidehoved" align="right">
        Rev.dato: -
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sidehoved">
      <td class="sidehoved">
        <em>X = revideret siden sidste udsendelse</em>
      </td>
      <td class="sidehoved" align="right">
        Side: <span class="page"></span>/<span class="topage"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nice catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this to your css

white-space:inherit;

```css
td.sidehoved {
    padding: 0px;
    white-space: inherit;
}
```